# Ошибка запуска развернутого приложения ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, развертывание, asp.net-core-mvc

Сборка проекта ASP.NET Core MVC проведена в VS2017 на версии Core 1.1, затем сделан Deploy на сервер WS 2012 R2 с развернутым IIS-8 и Runtime dotnet-win-x64.1.1.8. При запуске сайта получена ошибка:

> 500.19 with Error Code 0x8007000d.

При попытке принудительно сделать запуск `dotnet myapp.dll` получено сообщение:

[image: Скрин-ошибки].

Еще смущает содержание содержание конфигурации `ApplicationHost`, где в ветке `system.WebServer/Security/access` стоит: `access sslFlags="None"\`, хотя на сервере установлен сертификат и деплой я делал под 443 порт. Настройки сайта открываются с ошибкой: `\\\?\С:\MDS\web.config.`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, разобрался- синхронизировал run-time версии на сервере и клиенте.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/276344)

Comment: @NikitaSmith это является ответом на вопрос. Бессмысленно предлагать участнику, запостившему ответ на свой собственный вопрос вместо этого оставить самому себе комментарий, чтобы уточнить у самого себя что-то, или оставить замечания самому себе!

Comment: @Sublihim это исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос.